# Passing an R expression to a function and then changing its input parameters

Tags: r, function, expression

I would like to pass an R expression to a self-written function without
evaluating it at first and then manipulate an input parameter of
the R expression in that function.

I guess, it is easier to explain with an example.

In the below example function `fun1`, which should take
`lm(y ~ x, data=datatrain)` as an argument without
evaluating it at first, I would like to replace
`datatrain` in `lm(y ~ x, data=datatrain)` by
`newdatatrain` within the function (to be more precise,
`newdatatrain` will be `datatrain` with some columns
permuted within the function).

The reason why I need to provide `lm(y ~ x, data=datatrain)`
as a function argument is that the function should
also be able to take other types of models with possibly other
input parameters (e.g.,
`randomForest::randomForest(y ~ x, data=datatrain, replace=FALSE)`).

Here is what I tried:

```
# Does not run through:

fun1 <- function(mycall) {
  
  obj <- quote(mycall)
  
  newdatatrain <- data.frame(y=c(0.22,  1.09,  0.93, -0.02, -0.27), 
                             x=c(1.50,  0.53,  0.04, -2.43, -0.54))
  
  obj$data <- newdatatrain
  
  res <- eval(obj)
  
  return(res)
  
}

fun1(lm(y ~ x, data=datatrain))



# Does run through, but is not
# practical, because lm(y ~ x, data=datatrain)
# should be a function argument:


fun2 <- function(mycall) {
  
  obj <- quote(lm(y ~ x, data=datatrain))
  
  newdatatrain <- data.frame(y=c(0.22,  1.09,  0.93, -0.02, -0.27), 
                             x=c(1.50,  0.53,  0.04, -2.43, -0.54))
  
  obj$data <- newdatatrain
  
  res <- eval(obj)
  
  return(res)
  
}

fun2(lm(y ~ x, data=datatrain))
```

How could this be tackled?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry if I misunderstood, but can you not do something like this:

```
f <- function(estimator, formula, data) {
  newdata = data[sample(nrow(data),2),]
  predict(estimator(formula,data=data), newdata=newdata)
}

f(lm, y ~ x, datatrain)
f(glm, y ~ x, data=datatrain)
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, this solution would not work for me because instead of `lm` and `glm` the two functions I will be using do not have the same input parameters. But they do have the input parameter `data` in common, which I would like to change several times within my function.